# Using firebase authentication in apps with backend in Azure?

Tags: firebase, azure, oauth, firebase-authentication, azure-authentication

I want to use Firebase Authentication in my mobile app, however I want to host the mobile backend (REST API and database) on Azure. In this case, how would I get the identity information from Firebase over to Azure, e.g. how would I check in my Azure backend if a token sent from my mobile app to the Azure backend is valid, get the name of the logged in user etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [verify auth ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) sent from your app to your backend.